# Renaming words in WooCommerce status dashboard widget

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, widget, backend

I would like renaming words in WooCommerce status dashboard widget (see screenshot).

I use the following code and it works well for the title of the widget, but not for the marked words. What can be reason for that?

```php
add_filter(  'gettext',  'change_add_to_cart_message22', 10, 3 );
function change_add_to_cart_message22( $translated, $text, $domain  ) {
    global $pagenow;
    if( $text === 'on-hold' && $domain === 'woocommerce' && is_admin() && $pagenow === 'index.php' ){
        $translated = __( 'test', $domain );
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

[image]

---

I also tried this, but the result it's not good. It overwrites not only the text but also the HTML used for the link.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#woocommerce_dashboard_status .wc_status_list li.processing-orders").text(function () {
       return jQuery(this).text().replace("awaiting", "Websites:"); 
    });
});
```

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution I'd rather avoid, but this will be one of the quickest/easiest solutions.

Use jQuery. Make sure that the text you want to replace completely matches. For example, if this has already been translated, you should also apply it like this

So you get:

```php
// Prints scripts or data before the default footer scripts.
// This hook is for admin only and can’t be used to add anything on the front end.
function action_admin_footer() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $( 'ul.wc_status_list .processing-orders a' ).html( function( index, text ) {
                return text.replace( 'awaiting processing', 'first new text' );
            });
            
            $( 'ul.wc_status_list .on-hold-orders a' ).html( function( index, text ) {
                return text.replace( 'on-hold', 'second new text' );
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'action_admin_footer' );
```